# Jshint / PhpStorm: "Unresolved variable" when using jquery .data()

Tags: jquery, phpstorm, jshint, jsdoc

Phpstorm keeps telling me I have an undefined variable `input.connectto`

Html:
    `<div class="b-showColorinList" data-connectto="123456" data-othervalue="Lorem Ipsum">...`

JS:

```
$(document).on('click', '.b-showColorinList', function() {
    cm.showColorInList( $(this) );
});
```

And:

```
/**
 * Uses ajax to get other color in list view
 * @param {object} inputObj
 */
cm.showColorInList = function(inputObj) {
"use strict";

var input = inputObj.data(),
    parent = $("#"+input.connectto),
    othervalue = input.othervalue;
```

I know I can ignore a line in jshint, but is there any way to make it correct with jsdoc, example define `input` as an object

Comment: Why not `data("connectto")` if you are using jQuery (as in `$('.b-showColorinList').data('connectto');`) ?

Comment: Sorry, I shortened the code a little. There are actually more when one data field. Fixed that now

Comment: I understand that -- I'm just thinking -- if this is not mission-critical code or something that executed very often or needs to be executed instantly with little delays .. then why not call `data` method with specific parameter.

Comment: Try this (JSDoc): `/**
  * @typedef {Object} input
  * @property {String} connectto
  * @property {String} othervalue
  */` -- just format it nicely (comments do not allow multi-line fragments)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accordingly to [JSDoc docs](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-type.html) the proper way should using `@typedef` to define actual object structure (especially useful if it will be re-used later in another place) and `@type` to declare type of particular variable:

```
/**
 * @typedef {Object} MyInputData
 * @property {string} connectto 
 * @property {string} othervalue
 */

/** @type {MyInputData} */
var input = inputObj.data();
```

This one (with just `@typedef` and variable name as type name) seems to work in PhpStorm as well:

```
/**
 * @typedef {Object} input
 * @property {string} connectto 
 * @property {string} othervalue
 */
var input = inputObj.data();
```