# How to define globals with pre-defined members with jshint in Webstorm 10

Tags: webstorm, jshint

I've got a project that utilises a **.jshintrc** file in **Webstorm 10** (OSX). Most of all things work fine, including defining globals or pre-defined variables like "$" (jquery) and other globals in my particular project, like "ln" which is the top-level variable the code is organised under.

This "ln" variable can and is easily described as a global but I need to describe members of "ln" as pre-defined / globals as well, for example:

```
"ln.thing" (object)
"ln.thing.ignored" (Boolean)
"ln.thing.doSomething" (Function)
```

Despite adding the above to the "globals" field in the .jshintrc file Webstorm insists on producing a warning: "Unresolved variable thing".

How can I tell Webstorm that "ln" has members and they are pre-defined so should not produce a warning?

Comment: Info: Webstorm is using a bundled version 2.8.0 of jshint

Comment: Suggestion: use JSDoc's `@typedef` to describe the structure (members and their types). Then provide typehint (via `@type`) for your `ln` global variable. Overall it should be similar to http://stackoverflow.com/a/32994740/783119

Comment: In combination with jshint it looks like this will achieve what I want. Haven't used jsdoc much so overlooked it when searching for possible solutions as well as the fact the PhpStorm is a close relative to Webstorm. Feel free to set your comment as an answer :-)